# Objective C how to troubleshoot NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingException

Tags: objective-c, exception, core-data, ios4, locking

How can I troublehshoot _NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingException messages I am getting in the console? or debug it?

I am using background thread to update the core data context and the I am merging the context on the main thread with the main thread object, but I am geting these console message and I am unable to see where they are coming from.

```
objc[58487]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingException)
objc[58487]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x2235ec7 sp=0xb08e8a10] for exception 0x3dd42950
objc[58487]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x22622a6 sp=0xb08e8ad0] for exception 0x3dd42950
objc[58487]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x3dd42950 at 0x226234a
objc[58487]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
```

The first answer from @jonusx talked about using nested contexts to handle this situations, but what can be done to debug these exceptions when targeting the iOS 4 SDK?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from a change that can't be merged properly from two contexts. How exactly are you doing your background? You should try the new iOS 5 nested contexts for background saves. The parent can be in a private queue and the child (the background context) is in a thread confinement queue. Saves on the child are pushed up to the master context. After you're done in the background, just save the parent context to persist the changes to disk.